# Mendeley API - unable to authorize using client credentials authorization flow

Tags: curl, mendeley

I'm trying to authorize against the Mendeley API using the Client credentials authorization flow as described in the official [documentation](https://dev.mendeley.com/reference/topics/authorization_client_credentials.html).

However, when I try:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -u 799:1K2757WBBkLr9DOs -d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=all" https://api.mendeley.com/oauth/token
```

I get this response:

```
{"message":"Credentials are required to access this resource."}
```

Trying out the other option:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "https://api.mendeley.com/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=all&client_id=799&client_secret=1K2757WBBkLr9DOs"
```

makes no difference.

Comment: you probably shouldn't share your credentials like this... but personally it works with my credentials, are you sure the client_id is 799? mine is 4 integers, maybe double-check client_id/client_secret first

Comment: @Guillaume Those are not my real credentials. They are taken from the official documentation. Please check the link at the beginning of the question. On my machine I use my real client ID, which is 4 digits, and the real client secret.

Comment: ok have you tried using Postman? or even with simple JavaScript which I just tested and works too: ```fetch('https://api.mendeley.com/oauth/token', {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(`${clientId}:${clientSecret}`)}`},body: 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=all'}).then(response => response.json()).then(console.log);```

Comment: @Guillaume thanks for your help, but I tried Postman before, I tried now with your JS example, before tried wtih PHP Guzzle. Everything gives me the same response. There must be an issue with the client ID or the client secret, I suppose.

Comment: yes I suggest you contact them over [here](https://service.elsevier.com/app/chat/chat_launch/supporthub/mendeley/p/16075/) so they can sort your problem

Comment: @Guillaume Thank you for your help. I'm just plain stupid. In the section "My Apps" I clicked on "Generate secret" and copied the value and tried so many times. But I forgot to click "Update". After that it worked well. Mea culpa!

Comment: @cezar: You can add that as an answer. I made the same mistake.